# Issue with more-than using Unix in Python

Tags: python, unix, unix-timestamp

So I've been working on a script that calculates what seasonal event the current time is closer to, but I've ran into some issues regarding how to actually check. And before I get someone saying - "Yo, you know there's some easier way to pull the start off by using while loops?!" - I know, but that's really not what I asked. I just wanna see if there's any way to actually get the function to work correctly.

```
import datetime
yearlist = []
monthlist = []
daylist = []
holidaylist = []
#all of the time lists correspond to the ammount of years since 1970 - so, for instance, if you type that you were born in 2003, the number of seconds, displayed here
#will be yearlist[33], or 1041379200 seconds.
yearlist.append(0)#1970
yearlist.append(31536000)
yearlist.append(63072000)
yearlist.append(94694400)
yearlist.append(126230400)
yearlist.append(157766400)
yearlist.append(189302400)
yearlist.append(220924800)
yearlist.append(252460800)
yearlist.append(283996800)
yearlist.append(315532800)
yearlist.append(347155200)
yearlist.append(378691200)
yearlist.append(410227200)
yearlist.append(441763200)
yearlist.append(473385600)
yearlist.append(504921600)
yearlist.append(536457600)
yearlist.append(567993600)
yearlist.append(599616000)
yearlist.append(631152000)
yearlist.append(662688000)
yearlist.append(694224000)
yearlist.append(725846400)
yearlist.append(757382400)
yearlist.append(788918400)
yearlist.append(820454400)
yearlist.append(852076800)
yearlist.append(883612800)
yearlist.append(915148800)
yearlist.append(946684800)
yearlist.append(978307200)
yearlist.append(1009843200)
yearlist.append(1041379200)
yearlist.append(1072915200)
yearlist.append(1104537600)
yearlist.append(1136073600)
yearlist.append(1167609600)
yearlist.append(1199145600)
yearlist.append(1230768000)
yearlist.append(1262304000)
yearlist.append(1293840000)
yearlist.append(1325376000)
yearlist.append(1356998400)
yearlist.append(1388534400)
yearlist.append(1420070400)
yearlist.append(1451606400)
yearlist.append(1483228800)
yearlist.append(1514764800)
yearlist.append(1546300800)
yearlist.append(1577836800)
yearlist.append(1609459200)
yearlist.append(1640995200)
yearlist.append(1672531200)
yearlist.append(1704067200)
yearlist.append(1735689600)
yearlist.append(1767225600)
yearlist.append(1798761600)
yearlist.append(1830297600)
yearlist.append(1861920000)
yearlist.append(1893456000)
yearlist.append(1924992000)
yearlist.append(1956528000)
yearlist.append(1988150400)
yearlist.append(2019686400)
yearlist.append(2051222400)
yearlist.append(2082758400)
yearlist.append(2114380800)

monthlist.append(0)#january
monthlist.append(2592000)#february
monthlist.append(5184000)#march
monthlist.append(7776000)#arpril
monthlist.append(10368000)#may
monthlist.append(12960000)#june
monthlist.append(15552000)#july
monthlist.append(18144000)#august
monthlist.append(20736000)#september
monthlist.append(23328000)#october
monthlist.append(25920000)#november
monthlist.append(28512000)#december


daylist.append(0)#1
daylist.append(86400)#2
daylist.append(172800)#3
daylist.append(259200)#4
daylist.append(345600)#5
daylist.append(432000)#6
daylist.append(518400)#7
daylist.append(604800)#8
daylist.append(691200)#9
daylist.append(777600)#10
daylist.append(864000)#11
daylist.append(950400)#12
daylist.append(1036800)#13
daylist.append(1123200)#14
daylist.append(1209600)#15
daylist.append(1296000)#16
daylist.append(1382400)#17
daylist.append(1468800)#18
daylist.append(1555200)#19
daylist.append(1641600)#20
daylist.append(1728000)#21
daylist.append(1814400)#22
daylist.append(1900800)#23
daylist.append(1987200)#24
daylist.append(2073600)#25
daylist.append(2160000)#26
daylist.append(2246400)#27
daylist.append(2332800)#28
daylist.append(2419200)#29
daylist.append(2505600)#30
daylist.append(2592000)#31

#holiday list
holidaylist.append(30931200)#christmas

file = open("data.txt","a")
file.write("/Test write." + "\n")
time.sleep(2)
seconds=time.time()
print(seconds)
timedate=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:')
print(timedate)
file.write(timedate +"\n")
#time added

print("Hello, and welcome to the feel better about your life card generator - perfect for all of the depressives in your life.")
time.sleep(1)
name=input("OK, first things first. Have a name? ")
if name=="no":
    print("...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Oh.")
else:
    print(name + "? Jeez... I feel sorry for you.")
file.write("name = " + name + "\n")
    #check if time added





print("What about your Birthday - I'll be shocked if you don't have one!")
year=input("What was the year? ")
#year count starts here, btw
if year=="1970":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[0]
elif year=="1971":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[1]
elif year=="1972":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[2]
elif year=="1973":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[3]
elif year=="1974":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[4]
elif year=="1975":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[5]
elif year=="1976":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[6]
elif year=="1977":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[7]
elif year=="1978":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[8]
elif year=="1979":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[9]
elif year=="1980":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[10]
elif year=="1981":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[11]
elif year=="1982":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[12]
elif year=="1983":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[13]
elif year=="1984":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[14]
elif year=="1985":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[15]
elif year=="1986":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[16]
elif year=="1987":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[17]
elif year=="1988":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[18]
elif year=="1989":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[19]
elif year=="1990":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[20]
elif year=="1991":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[21]
elif year=="1992":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[22]
elif year=="1993":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[23]
elif year=="1994":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[24]
elif year=="1995":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[25]
elif year=="1996":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[26]
elif year=="1997":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[27]
elif year=="1998":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[28]
elif year=="1999":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[29]
elif year=="2000":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[30]
elif year=="2001":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[31]
elif year=="2002":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[32]
elif year=="2003":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[33]
elif year=="2004":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[34]
elif year=="2005":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[35]
elif year=="2006":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[36]
elif year=="2007":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[37]
elif year=="2008":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[38]
elif year=="2009":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[39]
elif year=="2010":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[40]
elif year=="2011":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[41]
elif year=="2012":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[42]
elif year=="2013":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[43]
elif year=="2014":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[44]
elif year=="2015":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[45]
elif year=="2016":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[46]
elif year=="2017":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[47]
elif year=="2018":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[48]
elif year=="2019":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[49]
elif year=="2020":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[50]
elif year=="2021":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[51]
elif year=="2022":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[52]
elif year=="2023":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[53]
elif year=="2024":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[54]
elif year=="2025":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[55]
elif year=="2026":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[56]
elif year=="2027":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[57]
elif year=="2028":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[58]
elif year=="2029":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[59]
elif year=="2030":
    birthyear=yearlist[0]+yearlist[60]
else:
    print("Damn, you're getting so old that even unix doesn't support your existence.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("What else can I say? I'm not gonna make the counter go negative, that'll make me have to re-write most of this.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Go on then, leave. You broke it by being old. Congrats.")


time.sleep(1)

month=input("What month? ")
if month=="january":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[0]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[0]
elif month=="february":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[1]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[1]
elif month=="march":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[2]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[2]
elif month=="april":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[3]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[3]
elif month=="may":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[4]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[4]
elif month=="june":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[5]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[5]
elif month=="july":
    birthyearmonth = birthtyear+monthlist[6]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[6]
elif month=="august":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[7]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[7]
elif month=="september":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[8]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[8]
elif month=="october":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[9]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[9]
elif month=="november":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[10]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[10]
elif month=="december":
    birthyearmonth = birthyear+monthlist[11]
    birthmonth = 0 + monthlist[11]
else:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("...of course you mistyped something. Typical.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Right, reset the shell - c'mon, this was you're fault.")
#That's the end of the month and year thing, future Laz.

time.sleep(1)
print("So - thus far we've got the year, and month. Logically, next is the day.")
time.sleep(2)
day=input("So, what date was it? ")
#here's the start of the final hurdle, Laz - don't mess this up.
if day=="1":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+1+daylist[0]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[0]
elif day=="2":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[1]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[1]
elif day=="3":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[2]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[2]
elif day=="4":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[3]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[3]
elif day=="5":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[4]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[4]
elif day=="6":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[5]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[5]
elif day=="7":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[6]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[6]
elif day=="8":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[7]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[7]
elif day=="9":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[8]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[8]
elif day=="10":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[9]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[9]
elif day=="11":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[10]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[10]
elif day=="12":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[11]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[11]
elif day=="13":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[12]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[12]
elif day=="14":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[13]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[13]
elif day=="15":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[14]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[14]
elif day=="16":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[15]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[15]
elif day=="17":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[16]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[16]
elif day=="18":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[17]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[17]
elif day=="19":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[18]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[18]
elif day=="20":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[19]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[19]
elif day=="21":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[20]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[20]
elif day=="22":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[21]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[21]
elif day=="23":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[22]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[22]
elif day=="24":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[23]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[23]
elif day=="25":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[24]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[24]
elif day=="26":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[25]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[25]
elif day=="27":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[26]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[26]
elif day=="28":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[27]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[27]
elif day=="29":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[28]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[28]
elif day=="30":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[29]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[29]
elif day=="31":
      birthfull = birthyearmonth+daylist[30]
      birthmonthday = birthmonth+daylist[30]
print(birthmonthday)
#Oooh, that was WAY harder to write than the year list.
if name=="admin":
    print("Whoops, I should've removed this - BUT SINCE IT HAS ACTUAL PURPOSE I GUESS NOT")
else:
    datetime1970 = int(seconds - yearlist[47])
    christmasfinal = holidaylist[0] - datetime1970
    print(christmasfinal)


birthactual=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(birthfull).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:')
print(birthactual)


if birthmonthday>christmasfinal:
    print("Christmas is closer. Also you gotta work on that card")


elif birthmonthday<christmasfinal:
    print("Birthday's closer, ya dingus")
```

And yes, I know I'm terrible at this.

And yes, this is my first Python project - it really shows.

EDIT: the problem with the code is that it constantly tells me that Christmas is closer, even if the provided date isn't. Also I should say that the final birth date isn't perfect (a few days out), but close enough to the point that it shouldn't matter to the user. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: I can't even imagine how long it must have taken you to write all these `if` statements. Props to you.

Comment: I remember my first program ever. It was horrible. Uh, you really should look into using loops.

Comment: my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: Manual loop unrolling...

Comment: Why all those `if` statements instead of something like `birthyear = yearlist[0] + yearlist[int(year) - 1970]`?

Comment: BTW, you know there's a module for working with dates and converting them to seconds?

Comment: @Barmar I know, it's in use at the start to convert the current time (I think that you're referring to that module?), but for some odd reason, I, at three AM, found this easier.

Comment: @Rawing The issue is that it keeps on returning with Christmas being sooner than the user-inputted date.

Comment: This program is so confusing, I can't figure out what things like `christmasfinal = holidaylist[0] - datetime1970` are doing. `datetime1970` is some calculation involving the current time, why should that affect when Christmas is?

Comment: @Barmar I guess datetime1970 is the current time, but minus the years - christmasfinal would be, going by that logic, albeit terrible logic, the current distance from christmas in seconds, at least to a certain extent.

Comment: `birthmonthday` is the number of seconds from the beginning of the year until the birthday. `christmasfinal` is the number of seconds from NOW until Christmas. Why would you compare these two things? If you want to know which is closer, you need to subtract the current time from each of them.

Comment: @Barmar birthmonthday is the month and day input added to the unix time of zero - then again, I can see where you're going with it not being compatible. After adding in a variable that shows the current amount of time until your birthday by adding 'birthsecondsto = birthmonthday - datetime1970' and changing more than/less than to work with the new variable, it still doesn't work if you've just had your birthday earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not comparing the right values. `birthmonthday` is the number of seconds from the beginning of the year until the user's birthday. `christmasfinal` is the number of seconds from now until Christmas. It makes little sense to compare these to each other. If you want to know which is closer, you need to subtract `birthmonthday` from `datetime1970` (the name of this variable is very weird, since it's the number of seconds from the beginning of 2017, not 1970), and compare that to `christmasfinal`. You also need to use the absolute value of the differences, since one could be negative and the other positive.

```
seconds_to_birthday = birthmonthday - datetime1970
if (abs(seconds_to_birthday) > abs(christmasfinal)):
    print("Christmas is closer. Also you gotta work on that card")
elif (abs(seconds_to_birthday) < abs(christmasfinal)):
    print("Birthday's closer, ya dingus")
else:
    print("We're exactly halfway between birthday and Christmas, you decide what to do")
```